Route all traffic **except return traffic** through NAT Gateway
I am fidgeting with NAT Gateways and netplan.
I need all traffic that was initiated by the machine, so to say, to go though the nat gateway, and all return traffic in response to inbound requests to be unaffected and use the default gateway.
So far the best I could do is explicitly specify an IP address (<ip_that_can_communicate_with_this_machine>) that is ignored by the nat gateway routing rule.
In essense, I need routing rules to branch not on IP addresses and IP subnets, but on traffic type - return traffic or self-initiated traffic.
Here's the netplan yaml config:
network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
        eth0:
            addresses:
            - <public_ip>/20
            - 10.19.0.14/16
            match:
                macaddress: <mac_1>
            mtu: 1500
            nameservers:
                addresses:
                - <dns_1>
                - <dns_2>
                search: []
            routes:
            -   to: <ip_that_can_communicate_with_this_machine>
                via: <original_gateway>
            set-name: eth0
        eth1:
            addresses:
            - <private_ip>/20
            match:
                macaddress: <mac_2>
            mtu: 1500
            nameservers:
                addresses:
                - <dns_3>
                - <dns_4>
                search: []
            routes:
            -   to: 0.0.0.0/0
                via: <private_ip_of_nat_gateway>
            set-name: eth1


It's a digitalocean machine that is connected to a vpc, the 10. addresses you see are private addresses that are part of the private subnet.
